# mysql joins - how to find all children that belongs to ALL parents

Tags: mysql, inner-join, not-exists

I have three mysql tables

```
items
===========
id    title

items_in_categories
============================
id    item_id    category_id

categories
===========
id    title
```

I want to find all the items that belong to **ALL** the stated categories. Not any one category, but ALL categories

Eg, if I want to search all the items that belongs to category id 3 and 5

the no. of possible categories to be searched can go up to as many as 20.

Eg, I want to get all the items that belongs to category id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, .... and 20

I would like to use as simple a way as possible.

I have tried AND and a nested NOT EXISTS as stated in the mysql manual.

Nothing worked.

**UPDATE:**
I came up with this.

```
select * from 
    (select count(*) as counter, item_id from items_in_categories 
        where category_id in (3, 5) group by item_id)getall 
where counter = 2
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I came up with this

select * from (select count(*) as counter, item_id from items_in_categories where category_id in (3, 5) group by item_id)getall where counter = 2

Is there a better way?

Comment: not bad, but 1.) comments are for comments. Answers are for answers :) 2.) you should do a distinct count, otherwise this will fail if you have multiple matches of 3, but no 5's

Comment: I see. So I should have given my own answer as an answer like other people as well yes?

Comment: ah.... you are right. there is a possibility of multiple matches of 3. I did not take care of that. Thank you, Justin

Comment: Glad to help. And, yes if you solve your answer before others, then you can put it as an answer, but only if you are sure it is the solution. You will have to wait 24+ hours to accept an answer of your own, though. This allows for others to work this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this can be prettied up and put into one query (You could nest the category count within the having instead of as a separate query...I just think this is more readable), but here is my shot at this:

```
DECLARE @CategoryCount INT;

SELECT @CategoryCount = COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS CategoryCount
FROM categories
WHERE category_id IN (3,5);

SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE item_id IN 
(
    SELECT item_id
    FROM items_in_categories
    WHERE items_in_categories.category_id IN (3,5)
    GROUP BY item_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category_id) = @CategoryCount
)
```

Comment: is your answer similar to my first attempt?

Comment: @kimsia Yes, the only difference is that I am using DISTINCT counts to make sure 2 rows with 3 do not work. The DISTINCT forces the results to only return if 3 AND 5 match (it ignores duplication of the same category)

Comment: I will accept this answer. I don't have too much time to wait for a better solution. Hopefully should there be a better one (I am not too hopeful), that answer gets upvoted even higher. Thank you Justin :)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that using the "IN" clause like this:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM items i
WHERE i.id IN (SELECT item_id from items_in_categories where category_id IN (3,5))
```

Comment: This will get matches that have 3, but not 5 (vice-versa). The OP wants results only if they have both 3 and 5

Comment: Shouldn't category_id IN (3,5) give both 3 and 5 results ?

Comment: @JustinPihony is right. IN clause gives a match if at least one category. Not ALL

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from items i , items_in_categories iic, categories c where i.id = iic.item_id and iic.category_id = c.id and c.id in(select * from category where id in(3,5))
```

if you are not getting distinct item from above query, you can add DISTINCT on item's id.

Comment: This will get matches that have either 3 or 5. The OP wants 3 AND 5.