# Evaluate specific grouped values in a single query?

Tags: mysql

I have a books database with categories and tags associated with books. I am trying to build a filter that will let users filter on multiple categories or tags and see books that have those tags or categories. It works fine with a single category or tag, but it falls apart if there are multiple tags or categories due to being grouped by book id.

```
SELECT books.id as id,title, sub_title,medium_image_url,
    amzn_url,amzn_review as review,SUBSTRING(kindle_price,2) as price,
    IFNULL(ROUND(combined_ratings.love/(combined_ratings.love+combined_ratings.hate)*100), 0) AS rating ,
    categories.category as category,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.id SEPARATOR ", ") as all_cats 
    FROM books 
    JOIN combined_ratings ON books.id = combined_ratings.book_id JOIN book_categories ON books.id = book_categories.book_id 
    JOIN categories ON book_categories.category_id = categories.id 
    WHERE (SUBSTRING(kindle_price,2) >= 0 
    AND SUBSTRING(kindle_price,2) <= 12 
    AND kindle_price <> "") 
    AND (IFNULL(ROUND(combined_ratings.love/(combined_ratings.love+combined_ratings.hate)*100), 0) >= 0 
    AND IFNULL(ROUND(combined_ratings.love/(combined_ratings.love+combined_ratings.hate)*100), 0) <= 100) 
    GROUP BY id 
    ORDER BY price ASC, rating DESC
```

I've tried using GROUP_CONCAT and HAVING, I just read about IN(), but I tried it and it doesn't work. All I really need to do now is do something like IN() to it, any suggestions?

EDIT: I used this and was able to get results for a singe category, but it only works once...
This works...

```
AND FIND_IN_SET( categories.id, '6' ) > 0
```

This does not

```
AND FIND_IN_SET( categories.id, '6' ) > 0 AND FIND_IN_SET( categories.id, '5' ) > 0
```

If I can get this to work it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on trying to use JOINs alone and went with sub queries. This works for me, it may not be ideal, but I can now filter as many tags or categories as I want.

```
SELECT id, title, author, image, sub_title, price, SUM(count) as count, rating FROM 
(
SELECT books.id as id, title, author, medium_image_url as image, sub_title, kindle_price as price, IFNULL(ROUND(combined_ratings.love/(combined_ratings.love+combined_ratings.hate)*100), 0) as rating , COUNT( DISTINCT category_id ) AS count 
FROM book_categories 
JOIN books ON book_categories.book_id = books.id 
JOIN authors ON books.author_id = authors.id 
JOIN combined_ratings ON books.id = combined_ratings.book_id 
WHERE category_id = 5 
OR category_id = 6 
OR category_id = 12 
GROUP BY book_categories.book_id 
HAVING count >= 3 
UNION ALL 
SELECT books.id as id, title, author, medium_image_url as image, sub_title, kindle_price as price, IFNULL(ROUND(combined_ratings.love/(combined_ratings.love+combined_ratings.hate)*100), 0) as rating , COUNT( DISTINCT tag_id ) AS count 
FROM book_tags JOIN books ON book_tags.book_id = books.id 
JOIN authors ON books.author_id = authors.id 
JOIN combined_ratings ON books.id = combined_ratings.book_id 
WHERE book_tags.tag_id = 22 
GROUP BY book_tags.book_id HAVING count >= 1 
) 
as b1 
WHERE (SUBSTRING(price,2) >= 0 
AND SUBSTRING(price,2) <= 20 AND price <> '') 
AND (rating >= 0 AND rating <= 100) 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING count = 4
ORDER BY price ASC, 
rating DESC
```

This works by checking to see if any results exist for any of the criteria and then counting the number of criteria matches. In the outer query I add up the two unioned queries and determine if the SUM() of those counts matches the total number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There was stackoverflow post a while ago. Please, [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883796/mysql-joins-how-to-find-all-children-that-belongs-to-all-parents/9883855#9883855).
Another way to go would be to create temporary tables each time and put there all tags and categories and then do a join.

Comment: I tried following the answer to the post you linked exactly and it doesn't work. I get all kinds of errors in MySQL. I'm also not sure how to create temporary tables as you suggested.